# Package to jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, package

UPDATE: Don't worry. User Error.  Would delete the question but cant with answers.

I am trying to use eclipse to create a jar of packages, *not* a runnable jar, which I can import into another project.

So far I have done this:

1. Create a new project
2. Create a package in that project (pkg.nme.with.dots)
3. Create a class in that package
4. Export -> Java -> Jar

The resultant .jar file has only one directory `META-INF`, and three files `.project`, `.classpath`, and `MyClass.class`.

If I try to `import pkg.nme.with.dots.MyClass;` I get a package not found error, despite adding the full path of the jar to my CLASSPATH.

I tried adding the jar as an external lib in eclipse but it is still not recognised.

Obviously I have exported it into a format that can't be `import`ed.  How do I export it correctly?

Comment: Is the class file placed in pkg/nme/with/dots directory inside the jar?

Comment: @javapirate no - but I can't imagine I have do do that manually. It has that path in my workspace but not in the jar.

Comment: Did you try as in: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm

Answer (score 4):

@trideceth12 I just tested exporting a sample package in my eclipse. and my folder structure works fine. not sure why yours is not working properly. you should check all your export settings. here's what mine looks like, and it exports fine.[image]

Answer (score 3):

when you create jar file using eclipse choose the export option ,in your jar creation wizard chosse your necessary folder ,then finish, for see  [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Look like your Java source is in Default package only. If you want to use this kind of import statement, considering moving the jar file to:

```
pkg/nme/with/dots
```

Comment: The source is in the correct package, but eclipse does not export the correct directory structure

Comment: Just tested locally, and it worked like a charm. Can you try doing the same on other IDE.